# AD authentication in Node js

Tags: node.js, express, azure-active-directory, angular6, server-side-rendering

I have created a serverside rendering angular application. I'm trying to authenticate the application using @azure/msal-angular - **0.1.4** (AD Authentication). When I run the application using the command

```
node app.js
```

```
ReferenceError: Window is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (serversiderendering\node_modules\@azure\msal-angular\dist\msal.module.js:25:3)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (serversiderendering\node_modules\@azure\msal-angular\dist\index.js:13:21)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
```

Kindly help me to find out what I'm missing. Or is there any other option to authenticate(Active Directory) serverside rendering application.

Thanks

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ldapjs](http://ldapjs.org/), it's very simple and easy to use.

```
var ldap = require('ldapjs');
var client = ldap.createClient({
  url: 'ldap://127.0.0.1:1389'
});

client.bind('cn=root', 'secret', function(err) {
  if(err){console.log(err);}
});
```